# IN clause causing high execution time

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sqlperformance, sql-tuning

I have a 118 line query similar to this:

```
select * from (The inner query with many joins) WHERE campus_code IN ('560','598')
```

The campus_code is getting generated by a function `f_get_bookstore(SSBSECT_TERM_CODE,SSBSECT_CRN) AS SSBSECT_CAMP_CODE` in the inner query. If I run the inner query alone its count is 18 & it is getting executed in 13 s. But if I add the `WHERE campus_code IN ('560','598')` then it is taking more than 2 min.

Another strange thing is, I have another query which is also like

`select * from (The inner query with many joins) WHERE campus_code IN ('560','598')`. Here the inner query slightly different than previous one. The inner query is fast & returning 92 rows. But here the `campus_code IN` filtering is fast even though it is working on 92 rows (unlike 18 rows for the previous query). Here also the campus_code is generated through the same function.

Can any body help to tune the query? Please tell what more info do you need.

This is the entire query:

```
    SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT 'columbusstate' bk_institution_id,
    'columbusstate.'
    || scbcrse_subj_code
    || '.'
    || scbcrse_crse_numb
    ||'.'
    || Ssbsect_Crn
    || '.'
    || ssbsect_term_code bk_section_id,
    ssbsect_camp_code AS campus_code,
    scbcrse_subj_code
    || '.'
    || scbcrse_crse_numb
    ||'.'
    || Ssbsect_Crn
    || '.'
    || ssbsect_term_code institution_section_id,
    ssbsect_crn short_description,
    scbcrse_title AS description,
    ssbsect_crn sections_ssbsect_crn,
    ssbsect_term_code sections_ssbsect_term_code,
    'na' instructor_first_name,
    'na' instructor_last_name,
    scbcrse_subj_code
    || '.'
    || scbcrse_crse_numb rel_institution_course_id,
    scbcrse_title     AS rel_course_description,
    scbcrse_title     AS rel_course_name,
    scbcrse_crse_numb AS course_short_desc,
    scbcrse_crse_numb course_number,
    stvterm_desc term_short_desc,
    stvterm_code rel_institution_term_id,
    section.ssbsect_crn,
    ssbsect_ssts_code AS ssbsect_ssts_code,
    'columbusstate.'
    || stvterm_code rel_bk_term_id,
    'columbusstate.'
    || scbcrse_subj_code
    || '.'
    || scbcrse_crse_numb rel_bk_course_id,
    ssbsect_seq_numb,
    ssbsect_enrl ssbsect_enrl,
    ssbsect_enrl estimated_enrl,
    ssbsect_max_enrl ssbsect_max_enrl,
    ssbsect_crn ssbsect_section_key,
    ssbsect_crn ssbsect_section_number,
    'parent' relationship,
    course.scbcrse_subj_code institution_department_id ,
    'DFLT' institution_division_id,
    'DFLT' division_short_desc
  FROM
    (SELECT *
    FROM
      (SELECT SSBSECT_TERM_CODE,
        SSBSECT_CRN,
        SSBSECT_SUBJ_CODE,
        SSBSECT_CRSE_NUMB,
        SSBSECT_PTRM_CODE,        
        SSBSECT_SEQ_NUMB,
        SSBSECT_SSTS_CODE,
        SSBSECT_MAX_ENRL,
        SSBSECT_ENRL,
        SSBSECT_PRNT_IND,
        f_get_bookstore(SSBSECT_TERM_CODE,SSBSECT_CRN) AS SSBSECT_CAMP_CODE
      FROM SSBSECT
      ) sect
    JOIN
      (SELECT *
      FROM
        (SELECT * FROM saturn.stvterm WHERE STVTERM_CODE >= '201401' 
        )
      ) term
    ON term.stvterm_code=sect.ssbsect_term_code
    ) section
  JOIN
    (SELECT C1.scbcrse_subj_code,
      C1.scbcrse_dept_code,
      C1.scbcrse_crse_numb,
      C1.scbcrse_title
    FROM saturn.scbcrse C1          
    LEFT JOIN saturn.scbcrse C2
    ON (C1.scbcrse_subj_code             = C2.scbcrse_subj_code       
    AND C1.scbcrse_crse_numb             = C2.scbcrse_crse_numb
    AND C1.scbcrse_eff_term              < C2.scbcrse_eff_term)
    WHERE c2.scbcrse_eff_term           IS NULL
    ) Course ON Course.scbcrse_subj_code = Section.ssbsect_subj_code
  AND scbcrse_crse_numb                  = section.ssbsect_crse_numb
  AND ssbsect_ssts_code                 IN ('A','V','X')
  LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT sirasgn_term_code sirasgn_term_code,
      sirasgn_crn,
      MAX(spriden_pidm) spriden_pidm,
      MAX(spriden_first_name) instructor_first_name,
      MAX(spriden_last_name) instructor_last_name
    FROM
      (SELECT Pidm spriden_pidm,
        Csu_Id SPRIDEN_ID,
        First_Name spriden_first_name,
        Last_Name spriden_last_name,        
        Mi spriden_mi,
        External_User_Id login,
        Email
      FROM Csuapps.Wfollett_Person
      ) persons
    JOIN
      ( SELECT * FROM saturn.sirasgn WHERE SIRASGN_PRIMARY_IND = 'Y'
      ) relations
    ON persons.spriden_pidm=relations.sirasgn_pidm
    GROUP BY sirasgn_crn,
      sirasgn_term_code
    ) instr ON section.ssbsect_term_code=instr.sirasgn_term_code
  AND section.ssbsect_crn               =instr.sirasgn_crn
  WHERE Course.scbcrse_subj_code        = 'ACCT'
  AND section.ssbsect_term_code         = '201702'
  )
WHERE campus_code IN ('560','1157')
```

Execution Plan:

```
PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 2063389120

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                                      | Name               | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                               |                    |    77 |   968K|       |  4364   (3)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  SORT ORDER BY                                 |                    |    77 |   968K|   624K|  4364   (3)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   VIEW                                         |                    |    77 |   968K|       |  4155   (3)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    COUNT                                       |                    |       |       |       |            |          |
|   4 |     VIEW                                       |                    |    77 |   967K|       |  4155   (3)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |      SORT ORDER BY                             |                    |    77 |   774K|       |  4155   (3)| 00:00:01 |

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|*  6 |       FILTER                                   |                    |       |       |       |            |          |
|*  7 |        HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER                   |                    |    77 |   774K|       |  4154   (3)| 00:00:01 |
|*  8 |         INDEX RANGE SCAN                       | SCBCRSE_KEY_INDEX  |    83 |  1494 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   9 |         NESTED LOOPS                           |                    |    77 |   772K|       |  4153   (3)| 00:00:01 |
|  10 |          NESTED LOOPS OUTER                    |                    |    23 |   229K|       |  4139   (3)| 00:00:01 |
|* 11 |           HASH JOIN OUTER                      |                    |    23 |  1656 |       |  3783   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|  12 |            NESTED LOOPS                        |                    |    23 |  1334 |       |     7   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  13 |             TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID        | STVTERM            |     1 |    22 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 14 |              INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                 | PK_STVTERM         |     1 |       |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 15 |             TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| SSBSECT            |    23 |   828 |       |     6   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 16 |              INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | SSBSECT_INDEX_SUBJ |    25 |       |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  17 |            VIEW                                |                    |  2172 | 30408 |       |  3775   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|  18 |             HASH GROUP BY                      |                    |  2172 |  8537K|    16M|  3775   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|* 19 |              HASH JOIN                         |                    |  4166 |    15M|       |  1364   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|  20 |               VIEW                             | VW_GBF_14          |  2312 | 18496 |       |   211   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|  21 |                HASH GROUP BY                   |                    |  2312 | 48552 |       |   211   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|* 22 |                 TABLE ACCESS FULL              | SIRASGN            |  2312 | 48552 |       |   210   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|  23 |               VIEW                             | WFOLLETT_PERSON    |  3714 |    14M|       |  1153   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|  24 |                SORT UNIQUE                     |                    |  3714 |   342K|       |  1153   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|  25 |                 UNION-ALL                      |                    |       |       |       |            |          |
|  26 |                  NESTED LOOPS                  |                    |     1 |    59 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  27 |                   NESTED LOOPS                 |                    |     1 |    59 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|* 28 |                    INDEX RANGE SCAN            | PK_GLBEXTR         |     1 |    38 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 29 |                    INDEX UNIQUE SCAN           | PK_GOBTPAC         |     1 |       |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  30 |                   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID  | GOBTPAC            |     1 |    21 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  31 |                  NESTED LOOPS                  |                    |  1912 |   130K|       |   605   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  32 |                   NESTED LOOPS                 |                    |  1912 |   130K|       |   605   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 33 |                    HASH JOIN                   |                    |  1912 | 93688 |       |    31   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  34 |                     VIEW                       | VW_SQ_2            |  3076 | 83052 |       |    10   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  35 |                      HASH GROUP BY             |                    |  3076 | 39988 |       |    10   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  36 |                       INDEX FULL SCAN          | PK_SIBINST         |  6243 | 81159 |       |    10   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 37 |                     TABLE ACCESS FULL          | SIBINST            |  3881 | 85382 |       |    21   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 38 |                    INDEX UNIQUE SCAN           | PK_GOBTPAC         |     1 |       |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  39 |                   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID  | GOBTPAC            |     1 |    21 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  40 |                  NESTED LOOPS                  |                    |  1801 | 41423 |       |   543   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|  41 |                   NESTED LOOPS                 |                    |  1801 | 41423 |       |   543   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|  42 |                    VIEW                        | VW_DTP_6100A9C4    |  1801 |  3602 |       |     3  (34)| 00:00:01 |
|  43 |                     HASH UNIQUE                |                    |  1801 | 23413 |       |     3  (34)| 00:00:01 |
|* 44 |                      INDEX RANGE SCAN          | PK_SIRASGN         |  4161 | 54093 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 45 |                    INDEX UNIQUE SCAN           | PK_GOBTPAC         |     1 |       |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  46 |                   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID  | GOBTPAC            |     1 |    21 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  47 |           VIEW PUSHED PREDICATE                |                    |     1 | 10165 |       |    16  (25)| 00:00:01 |
|* 48 |            FILTER                              |                    |       |       |       |            |          |
|  49 |             NESTED LOOPS                       |                    |     1 | 10164 |       |    16  (25)| 00:00:01 |

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  50 |              NESTED LOOPS                      |                    |     1 |    79 |       |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 51 |               FILTER                           |                    |       |       |       |            |          |
|  52 |                NESTED LOOPS OUTER              |                    |     1 |    60 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  53 |                 NESTED LOOPS                   |                    |     1 |    42 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  54 |                  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID   | SSBSECT            |     1 |    24 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 55 |                   INDEX UNIQUE SCAN            | PK_SSBSECT         |     1 |       |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 56 |                  INDEX RANGE SCAN              | SCBCRSE_KEY_INDEX  |     1 |    18 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 57 |                 INDEX RANGE SCAN               | SCBCRSE_KEY_INDEX  | 15046 |   264K|       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 58 |               INDEX RANGE SCAN                 | PK_SIRASGN         |     1 |    19 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  59 |              VIEW                              | WFOLLETT_PERSON    |     1 | 10085 |       |    12  (34)| 00:00:01 |
|  60 |               SORT UNIQUE                      |                    |     3 |   304 |       |    12  (34)| 00:00:01 |

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  61 |                UNION ALL PUSHED PREDICATE      |                    |       |       |       |            |          |
|  62 |                 NESTED LOOPS                   |                    |     1 |    59 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  63 |                  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID   | GOBTPAC            |     1 |    21 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 64 |                   INDEX UNIQUE SCAN            | PK_GOBTPAC         |     1 |       |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 65 |                  INDEX RANGE SCAN              | PK_GLBEXTR         |     1 |    38 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  66 |                 NESTED LOOPS                   |                    |     1 |    70 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  67 |                  NESTED LOOPS                  |                    |     1 |    70 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  68 |                   NESTED LOOPS                 |                    |     1 |    48 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  69 |                    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID | GOBTPAC            |     1 |    21 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 70 |                     INDEX UNIQUE SCAN          | PK_GOBTPAC         |     1 |       |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  71 |                    VIEW                        | VW_SQ_1            |     1 |    27 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  72 |                     SORT GROUP BY              |                    |     1 |    13 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 73 |                      INDEX RANGE SCAN          | PK_SIBINST         |     2 |    26 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 74 |                   INDEX UNIQUE SCAN            | PK_SIBINST         |     1 |       |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 75 |                  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID   | SIBINST            |     1 |    22 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  76 |                 NESTED LOOPS                   |                    |     1 |    23 |       |     4  (25)| 00:00:01 |
|  77 |                  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID   | GOBTPAC            |     1 |    21 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 78 |                   INDEX UNIQUE SCAN            | PK_GOBTPAC         |     1 |       |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 79 |                  VIEW                          | VW_DTP_32C68FB6    |     1 |     2 |       |     3  (34)| 00:00:01 |
|  80 |                   SORT UNIQUE                  |                    |     2 |    26 |       |     3  (34)| 00:00:01 |
|* 81 |                    INDEX RANGE SCAN            | PK_SIRASGN         |     2 |    26 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  82 |          TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED   | SCBCRSE            |     3 |   126 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|* 83 |           INDEX RANGE SCAN                     | SCBCRSE_KEY_INDEX  |     1 |       |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - filter(("from$_subquery$_002"."CAMPUS_CODE"='1157' OR "from$_subquery$_002"."CAMPUS_CODE"='560') AND "R">=1 
              AND "R"<=1500)
   6 - filter("C2"."SCBCRSE_EFF_TERM" IS NULL)
   7 - access("C1"."SCBCRSE_SUBJ_CODE"="C2"."SCBCRSE_SUBJ_CODE"(+) AND 
              "C1"."SCBCRSE_CRSE_NUMB"="C2"."SCBCRSE_CRSE_NUMB"(+))

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       filter("C1"."SCBCRSE_EFF_TERM"<"C2"."SCBCRSE_EFF_TERM"(+))
   8 - access("C2"."SCBCRSE_SUBJ_CODE"(+)='ACCT')
  11 - access("SSBSECT_TERM_CODE"="INSTR"."SIRASGN_TERM_CODE"(+) AND "SSBSECT_CRN"="INSTR"."SIRASGN_CRN"(+))
  14 - access("STVTERM"."STVTERM_CODE"='201702')
  15 - filter("SSBSECT_SSTS_CODE"='A' OR "SSBSECT_SSTS_CODE"='V' OR "SSBSECT_SSTS_CODE"='X')
  16 - access("SSBSECT_SUBJ_CODE"='ACCT' AND "SSBSECT_TERM_CODE"='201702')
       filter("SSBSECT_TERM_CODE"='201702')
  19 - access("PIDM"="ITEM_1")
  22 - filter("SIRASGN"."SIRASGN_TERM_CODE"='201702' AND "SIRASGN_PRIMARY_IND"='Y')
  28 - access("GLBEXTR_APPLICATION"='STUDENT' AND "GLBEXTR_SELECTION"='CURR_ENRL' AND "GLBEXTR_CREATOR_ID"='GSHOUL')
  29 - access("GOBTPAC_PIDM"=TO_NUMBER("GLBEXTR_KEY"))

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  33 - access("A"."SIBINST_TERM_CODE_EFF"="MAX(B.SIBINST_TERM_CODE_EFF)" AND "ITEM_2"="A"."SIBINST_PIDM")
  37 - filter("A"."SIBINST_FCST_CODE"='AC' AND "A"."SIBINST_FCTG_CODE"<>'EMPL')
  38 - access("A"."SIBINST_PIDM"="GOBTPAC_PIDM")
  44 - access("SIRASGN_TERM_CODE">="TOOLS"."GETTERMCODE"(NULL,SYSDATE@!))
  45 - access("ITEM_1"="GOBTPAC_PIDM")
  48 - filter("SSBSECT_TERM_CODE">='201602' AND "SSBSECT_TERM_CODE"='201702')
  51 - filter("C2"."SCBCRSE_EFF_TERM" IS NULL)
  55 - access("SSBSECT_TERM_CODE"="SSBSECT_TERM_CODE" AND "SSBSECT_CRN"="SSBSECT_CRN")
       filter("SSBSECT_TERM_CODE"='201702')
  56 - access("SSBSECT_SUBJ_CODE"="C1"."SCBCRSE_SUBJ_CODE" AND "SSBSECT_CRSE_NUMB"="C1"."SCBCRSE_CRSE_NUMB")
  57 - access("C1"."SCBCRSE_SUBJ_CODE"="C2"."SCBCRSE_SUBJ_CODE"(+) AND 

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
              "C1"."SCBCRSE_CRSE_NUMB"="C2"."SCBCRSE_CRSE_NUMB"(+) AND "C1"."SCBCRSE_EFF_TERM"<"C2"."SCBCRSE_EFF_TERM"(+) AND 
              "C2"."SCBCRSE_EFF_TERM"(+) IS NOT NULL)
  58 - access("REL"."SIRASGN_TERM_CODE"="SSBSECT_TERM_CODE" AND "REL"."SIRASGN_CRN"="SSBSECT_CRN")
       filter("REL"."SIRASGN_TERM_CODE"="SSBSECT_TERM_CODE" AND "REL"."SIRASGN_TERM_CODE"='201702' AND 
              "REL"."SIRASGN_CRN"="SSBSECT_CRN")
  64 - access("GOBTPAC_PIDM"="REL"."SIRASGN_PIDM")
  65 - access("GLBEXTR_APPLICATION"='STUDENT' AND "GLBEXTR_SELECTION"='CURR_ENRL' AND "GLBEXTR_CREATOR_ID"='GSHOUL')
       filter(TO_NUMBER("GLBEXTR_KEY")="REL"."SIRASGN_PIDM" AND "GOBTPAC_PIDM"=TO_NUMBER("GLBEXTR_KEY"))
  70 - access("GOBTPAC_PIDM"="REL"."SIRASGN_PIDM")
  73 - access("B"."SIBINST_PIDM"="REL"."SIRASGN_PIDM")
  74 - access("A"."SIBINST_PIDM"="REL"."SIRASGN_PIDM" AND "A"."SIBINST_TERM_CODE_EFF"="MAX(B.SIBINST_TERM_CODE_EFF)")

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       filter("A"."SIBINST_PIDM"="GOBTPAC_PIDM" AND "ITEM_1"="A"."SIBINST_PIDM")
  75 - filter("A"."SIBINST_FCST_CODE"='AC' AND "A"."SIBINST_FCTG_CODE"<>'EMPL')
  78 - access("GOBTPAC_PIDM"="REL"."SIRASGN_PIDM")
  79 - filter("ITEM_1"="GOBTPAC_PIDM")
  81 - access("SIRASGN_TERM_CODE">="TOOLS"."GETTERMCODE"(NULL,SYSDATE@!) AND "SIRASGN_PIDM"="REL"."SIRASGN_PIDM")
       filter("SIRASGN_PIDM"="REL"."SIRASGN_PIDM")
  83 - access("C1"."SCBCRSE_SUBJ_CODE"='ACCT' AND "C1"."SCBCRSE_CRSE_NUMB"="SSBSECT_CRSE_NUMB")

139 rows selected.
```

Comment: Please run an explain plan and show the output.

Comment: Actually I don't have the permission for that. I will ask for it & upload here

Comment: Try to move the where into the subquery:     (SELECT *
    FROM
      (SELECT SSBSECT_TERM_CODE,
....
    ON term.stvterm_code=sect.ssbsect_term_code
 HERE--> WHERE campus_code IN ('560','598')
    ) section

Comment: @PeterRing No luck. Still taking 2.4 min

Comment: "I don't have the permission for that."  This never ceases to amaze me.  An explain plan is ALWAYS the first tool to check for query performance.  This is like asking a mechanic why an engine is having issues, but then refusing to turn the keys over to the mechanic (or refusing to start the car for him) so that he can even attempt to diagnose the issue.

Comment: @KrisJohnston: I absolutely agree with you. But the scene is different here. First of all I am a java developer & not the correct person to do a sql tuning because I don't have enough knowledge on database part. 2ndly the databases are in a remote location & we only have limited permission (only read). We have to make a ssh tunnel & connect through it & fire some query. Thats it. You can do nothing more.  But I can get those by asking our client.

Comment: @KrisJohnston I have uploaded the explain plan. Can you help?

Comment: @OldProgrammer I have uploaded the explain plan. Can you help?

Answer (score 2):

The performance of your query depends on the details, that we don't know, and on the joins. In general, if the joins result in a huge set of rows, that will eat a lot of cpu and ram. So try to add `where` clauses that minimize the number of rows in the joins.

Said in an other way, just imagine you are the cpu. Go through your query and try to estimate the number of rows that you need to process, and how you could limit that number of rows.

Are you using an index on crucial tables to speed up selects? Are you modifying the search column used in an index, so that the index does not work? Stuff like this is very important.

Good luck!

---

update:

The plan shows to me that most cpu is burned for the outermost query, something that you already noticed in the timing measurements. My strategy would be to try to move the outermost where-clause towards the inner queries. If the database engine can apply the where-clause in an earlier phase, the query will need less memory and cpu.

Now it is not possible to see to which table each output field belongs. If I where you I would give EVERY table in each FROM an alias.

For the sake of testing performance, and for posting here, you could simplify the lists of output fields. Leave out fields that are not required by outer queries, or use asterisk. Also, try to present a perfectly pretty printed query.

Apart from the Plan, could you get some info on memory usage? With the outer query, perhaps it needs to get a lot of data in memory before outputting results. Just imagine if this results in exhausting ram and needs swap, that will cost a lot of time. Memory use may also come from holding a lock on possibly big tables, so do not get fooled by your 'just 18 rows' of output.

Comment: The inner query containing the joins is getting executed within 13 s. So do you think there is something wrong there ??

Comment: Not necessarily. If the data is big, the query complex and your cpu has finite speed, 13 s may be reasonable.

Comment: The problem is the inner query is taking 13s. But if I run including the WHERE campus_code IN ('560','598') then it is taking 2.4 min

Comment: The extra where clause means that all rows must be individually compared with two string values. Linear search. How many rows? Many many rows? What kind of disk? SSD, or a remote network drive? Why not create a test query with just that where clause?

Comment: Ram is also important. Is it swapping a lot, or is there enough ram to hold the entire data set? Running entirely in ram is about 1000 times faster than using disk a lot.

Comment: The inner query is returning only 18 rows. I don't have enough info on the infrastructure but I can get that.

Comment: @Roland You seem to be fixated on platform issues; RAM, SSD, swapping etc.  Sumit has already demonstrated that the platform can return data in 13 seconds. So why do you think that platform fiddling will solve the problem of an additional predicate? (rhetorical question). Now, if only we could get some execution plans, we could find the real root cause....

Comment: @BobC Others seem fixated on query issues. The truth is that the runtime depends on both hardware and query issues. Without knowing anything about his hardware, and having no execution plan, for me it is'nt decided what is the root cause.

Comment: @Roland  I have uploaded the explain plan. Can you help?

Comment: @BobC I have uploaded the explain plan. Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I'm going to put this in a "answer", since comments seem to be ignored.

The only way to **know** what is going on and how to fix your problem is to get the execution plan. Otherwise every answer is a guess. You may get lucky that a guess works, but then you will never know why. So please help us to help you.

To get an execution plan (for both the queries with and without the WHERE clause), run this after your query...

```
set lines 500
set pages 10000

select * from table( dbms_xplan.display_cursor( null, null, 'TYPICAL' ));
```

Comment: I will give it a try today. Thanks :)

Comment: Hi I have uploaded the execution plan. Can you please help me?

Comment: OK, I'm gonna request a slight variation of the plan; and can you do it in sqlplus. This will give runtime stats.  alter session set statistics_level=ALL;  select * from table( dbms_xplan.display_cursor( null, null, 'ALLSTATS LAST' ) );

Comment: I have uploaded the complete explain plan. Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

Is campus_code an integer? If it is, try removing the apostrophes, like this:

```
WHERE campus_code IN (560,598)
```

Otherwise, each value gets converted before being compared, and that can take a lot of time.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately its not integer :(

Comment: Would removing the apostrophes like i suggested generate an error?

Comment: No, but it is still taking 2.4 min to execute.

Comment: Without an execution plan or (preferably) a SQL Monitor report, all the answers will be guesses.

Comment: Well, the next possible culprit is the lack of an index on that column (campus_code) or on the columns that are used to generate it.

Comment: @MihaiOvidiuDrăgoi It might be possible though I have to check. But one point. camcus_code is getting created by a function & it is not a real table or view column. So can I create an index on it? I will upload the execution plan soon.

Comment: Adding proper indexes to the columns used to generate the codes should make a difference

Comment: Hi I have uploaded the execution plan so thet you can get more insight about the problem. Can you please help me analyzing it

Comment: @MihaiOvidiuDrăgoi I have uploaded the complete explain plan. Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

What you observe is by 99% a merging predicates in an inline view.

This works typically fine and helps performance as illustrated on an example below.

**Sample Data**

```
 create table T1 as
 select 'xxxx'||rownum crampus_code from dual connect by level <= 100000;

 create index idx1 on t1(crampus_code);
```

This query can take a substantial  time on a large table as the whole table must be accessed.

```
 select crampus_code, count(*) from T1 group by crampus_code;
```

A following query using the previous query as a subquery can be very effective. How?

The `WHERE` clause in `MERGE` in the subquery and only the data for the two keys are accessed (index) and aggregated.

```
with agg as
(
    select 
        a.crampus_code, count(*) 
    from 
        T1 a  
    group by 
        crampus_code
)
select * 
from agg
where crampus_code in ('xxxx42','xxxx399');
```

The proof is in the execution plan (that you don't provided)

```
| Id  | Operation            | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT     |      |     2 |    48 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  SORT GROUP BY NOSORT|      |     2 |    48 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   INLIST ITERATOR    |      |       |       |            |          |
|*  3 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN  | IDX1 |     2 |    48 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   3 - access("A"."CRAMPUS_CODE"='xxxx399' OR 
              "A"."CRAMPUS_CODE"='xxxx42')
```

You see the table is accesse via index for only the two keys.

**Your Case**

This is only speculation but IMO during the merge predicate phase you get a much worst execution plan that without it.

This explain the increase in elapsed time by addin the `WHERE` clause.

Only if you show both plans (subquery and the query with `WHERE`) you can be sure...

**Workaround**

So what can you do if the predicate merge destroys the performance?

Simple turn it off. Unfortunately you must use an undocumented hint [MATERIALIZE](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:649529000346677493), that set up the result of the query as temporary table 
and the WHERE predicate will be applied on it.

This should work for your 18 rows. I'm not sure, but thing you must rewrite query using the subquery factoring (WITH).

```
with agg as
(select  /*+ MATERIALIZE */ a.crampus_code, count(*) from T1 a  group by crampus_code)
select * from agg
where crampus_code in ('xxxx42','xxxx399'); 

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                  | Name                        | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT           |                             | 97325 |  3516K|    94   (5)| 00:00:02 |
|   1 |  TEMP TABLE TRANSFORMATION |                             |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   LOAD AS SELECT           | SYS_TEMP_0FD9D673A_CE046F62 |       |       |            |          |
|   3 |    HASH GROUP BY           |                             | 97325 |  2281K|    41  (10)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL      | T1                          | 97325 |  2281K|    37   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  5 |   VIEW                     |                             | 97325 |  3516K|    54   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|   6 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL       | SYS_TEMP_0FD9D673A_CE046F62 | 97325 |  2281K|    54   (2)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   5 - filter("CRAMPUS_CODE"='xxxx399' OR "CRAMPUS_CODE"='xxxx42')
```

Comment: Hi I have uploaded the execution plan so thet you can get more insight about the problem. Can you please help me analyzing it?

Comment: @SumitPal please post the execution plan in a text form as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975406/how-to-describe-performance-issue-in-relational-database?answertab=oldest#tab-top) inclusive the predicate information (which is crutial).

Comment: I have uploaded the explain plan. Can you help?

Comment: @Ajit So this is your slow query running 2 minutes and if you run the subquery only ist is as quick as  13 seconds? If so you need to check **both** execution plans and spot some fundamental change leading to the drop of the elapsed time. Alternatively you may try to reformulate the query as follows:
`with agg as
(select  /*+ MATERIALIZE */ 'columbusstate' bk_.. rest of your subquery )
select * from agg
WHERE campus_code IN ('560','1157')`